# how to reference a higher class within an anonymous class

Tags: java, android, class, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

I have this code:

```
public class Home extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //...
            //at some point I have
            s.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

              @Override
              public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                      boolean fromUser) {

                  ContextNotionLevel ctnl=new ContextNotionLevel(this);
// <-- how can I reference Home class here to replace **this**, which as it is points to OnSeekBarChangeListener
              }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
 ContextNotionLevel ctnl=new ContextNotionLevel(Home.this);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Home.this` to refer to the Home object.